# How can I convert all my slides in Power Point into .jpg pictures?

Tags: conversion, microsoft-powerpoint, photos

i used to know hot to do it, but I forgot. How can I convert all my slides in Power Point into .jpg pictures?

Comment: It got a vote, someone clearly thought otherwise.....

Answer (score 6):

Open the PowerPoint presentation (PPT or PPS). 
Go to File > Save As > Other formats 
Now you will see lot of options for in the combo box. Select JPEG format and save. 
This will save all your file into a folder with same name as your ppt or pps name

Comment: @bri: just in case you want to use your images for presentation: you can easily convert your existing presentation to a slide show of images just in two clicks using this tool: http://j.mp/pptraster (I am the author of this tool).